# Gulp неправильно выдаёт html с фримаркерными конструкциями

Tags: html, gulp, frontend, freemarker

Есть email-шаблоны в html c freemarker'ными вставками. При пропускании их через gulp-таск (замена изображений по ссылкам на `data:image/png;base64`) Gulp форматирует по-своему фримаркерные конструкции, убирая camelCase и вставляя ненужные закрывающие теги.

Пример:

```
<#assign minorAmount = minorAmount + tips\.amount?number>
```

Преобразовывается в:

```
<#assign minoroamount="minorAmount" +="" tips\.amount?number="">
//html-текст
</#assign></html>
```

Для замены изображений используется только `gulp-img64`, больше ничего в потоке нет. Куда копать?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно экранировать вставки через `|`. Ниже привожу пример:

```
.block1
   | <#assign minorAmount = minorAmount + tips\.amount?number>
```

Вышеприведенный код скомпилируется в:

```
<div class="block1">
   <#assign minorAmount = minorAmount + tips\.amount?number>
</div>
```

Comment: Хм, не помогло. Дело в том, что тут не используется pug, изначально идёт html.Эти символы — | — переносятся в конечный файл. Единственное предназначение галпа в данном случае — менять картинки на `base64`.

Comment: @ИгорьН подумал, что вы используете Pug

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему выносом фримаркерных конструкций в отдельные файлы и последующим инклюдом их в html-файл

Comment: Но это костыльно. Хотелось бы всё же узнать причину таких действий галпа